# Insercion de datos en base de datos con symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Disculpen, tengo una duda sobre como insertar datos en dos tablas con symfony.
El caso es que tengo una tabla usuario y una tabla persona con relación 1 a 1 entonces para insertar un usuario necesitamos de una persona. [image: Base de datos]

alguien que me pueda guiar sobre la inserción de datos con symfony. ya he creado mis entidades. pero ahora mi duda es como seria el código en el controlador para realizar esta inserción. y como se le hace para traer los datos de un usuario y de su persona asociada para mostrarlos en front end
¿Es necesario una vista?
Esto ya lo he realizado en Java. Pero en PHP soy realmente nuevo y mas con symfony. Las inserciones que solo conllevan una clase en symfony no me presentan un problema pero aquí si realmente me quede sin ideas. 
Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

No cambia mucho con respecto a la inserción de una entidad sin relación. Sólo hay que agregar la Entidad relacionada al objeto. Por ejemplo, al usuario hay que agregarle la persona, o a la persona agregarle el usuario (depende de como esté configurada la relación). Luego Doctrine se encarga de guardar ambos objetos en la base de datos.

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$usuario = new Usuario;
$persona = new Persona;

$usuario->setPersona($persona);
$entityManager->persist($usuario);
$entityManager->flush();
```

**Cómo traer los datos de un usuario**

Se puede traer los datos de una de las entidades y luego se obtiene la otra, por medio de la relación. Así:

```
$usuario = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Usuario::class)
    ->find($id);

$persona = $usuario->getPersona();
```

Ya luego puede mandar las variables $usuario y $persona a la plantilla de twig. Para más información le recomiendo ver la [documentación oficial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)